# Biot-Savart applied to non-closed current distribution

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Suppose you wanted to calculate the magnetic field from a current distribution J in a small volume where the current was not closed in that volume. Putting aside whether this is physically meaningful, one could naively just apply Biot-Savart integral

$$\mathbb{B}_{BS}= \frac{\mu_{0}}{4\pi}\nabla\times\int_{V}{\frac{\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|}dV'}$$

One can recover Ampere's law by taking the curl of this (and doing some nifty manipulation and use of divergence theorem) and assuming solenoidality of J and that the system is unbounded (i.e. closed J).

$$\frac{\nabla\times\mathbf{B}_{BS}}{\mu_{0}}  =  \mathbf{J} -\frac{1}{4\pi}\nabla\int_{V}{\frac{\nabla'\cdot\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|}dV'} + 
\frac{1}{4\pi} \nabla \int_{\delta V}{\mathbf{n'}\cdot\frac{\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r'}-\mathbf{r}|} dS'} 
$$

where the last two terms vanish by the above solenoidality and unbounded volume (closed J) arguments.

So, now what happens if our J is not closed? The very last term on the right hand side $\mathbf{J}_{corr} = \frac{1}{4\pi} \nabla \int_{\delta V}{\mathbf{n'}\cdot\frac{\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r'}-\mathbf{r}|} dS'} $ could be non-zero, as e.g., current flux leaves the volume.

Does this "boundary correction" term have an associated magnetic field?

Something that may be related it that the last two terms in the above equation for $\nabla\times\mathbf{B}_{BS}$ above look like part of the Helmholtz decomposition of $\mathbf{J}$

$$\mu_{0}\mathbf{J} = \nabla \times \mathbf{B} + \nabla\phi \nonumber $$

$$\mathbf{B} =  \frac{\mu_{0}}{4\pi}\int_{V}{\frac{\nabla'\times\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r'})} {|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|}dV'} - \frac{\mu_{0}}{4\pi}\int_{\delta V}{\mathbf{n'}\times\frac{\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|}dS'} $$

$$\mathbf{\phi} = \frac{\mu_{0}}{4\pi}\int_{V}{\frac{\nabla'\cdot\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r'})} {|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|}dV'} - \frac{\mu_{0}}{4\pi}\int_{\delta V}{\mathbf{n'}\cdot\frac{\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|}dS'}$$

so does this mean that there is no real magnetic field that is associated with this "boundary correction" term? Does this go back to the problem of trying to calculate the magnetic field from a non-closed current distribution?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current

Comment: I don't think displacment current applies here. BS integral equation is a solution of the static Ampere's law, with the displacement current zero. Given that this proboem starts with the Ampere's law without the displacement current, it's not relevant to this problem.